# How can I save the value from radio input as boolean?

Tags: ajax, input

I need to save the value selected from the input as a boolean to the database. In this way, the other button I use registers as 0 1 in the yield database. How can I save true as false. Note: it saves false no matter what you choose to the database. It has not changed before or after this procedure.

```js
"showinrow": $(".message_sh:checked").val(),
```

```html
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
  <label class="btn btn-primary active">
    <input type="radio" class="message_sh" name="options1" value="True"> True
  </label>
  <label class="btn btn-primary">
    <input type="radio" class="message_sh" name="options1" value="False" checked=""> False
  </label>
</div>
```

Comment: $(".message_sh:checked").val() === 'True'

Comment: I want it to save as true or false according to the selected value. I don't want it to always set as true

Answer (score 0):

As i say in the comment you can compare value with the string 'True';

```js
$(".message_sh:checked").val() === 'True
```

### Demonstration

```js
$('.submit').on('click', function(){
  const isTrue = $(".message_sh:checked").val() === 'True'
  if(isTrue){
    alert('This is true')
  }else{
    alert('This is false')
  }
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="btn-group btn-group-toggle" data-toggle="buttons">
    <label class="btn btn-primary active">
        <input type="radio" class="message_sh" name="options1" value="True"> True
    </label>
    <label class="btn btn-primary">
        <input type="radio" class="message_sh" name="options1" value="False" checked=""> False
    </label>
  <button class="submit">submit</button>
</div>
```

Comment: `  data: {
   "newss": {
    "name": $('#Name').val(),
    "description": $('#Description').val(),
    "detayimage": $('#DetayImage').val(),
    "datedesc": $('#DateDesc').val(),
    "status": $(".message_pri:checked").val(),
    "showinrow": $(".message_sh:checked").val(),
    "langid": 1
   }
  },`

Comment: Verilerin içinde olup olmadığını kontrol edemiyorum :') @ZecKa

Comment: @hbaa in english please XD

Comment: English is bad.. thanks for the translation :')

Comment: not using if else in ajax 'data'

Comment: `data: {
   "newss": {
    "name": $('#Name').val(),
    "description": $('#Description').val(),
    "detayimage": $('#DetayImage').val(),
    "datedesc": $('#DateDesc').val(),
    "status": $(".message_pri:checked").val(),
    "showinrow": $(".message_sh:checked").val(),
    "langid": 1
   }
  },  `

Comment: So just use ternary operator...